# How can I remove the "low quality post" warning text from a valid answer?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, accepted-answer

Consider:

*[How to search (grep) across all files, in all branches, in all repos in Stash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33386051/how-to-search-grep-across-all-files-in-all-branches-in-all-repos-in-stash)*

There popped up an answer from `James Riche` simply referring me to a new plugin. The answer was immediately marked as low quality.

Actually, it's a fair answer, and I plan to accept it, since it will provide the most benefit to anyone wanting an answer to the same question, and I have tested the plugin in question.

But I am worried the "warning" (*This does not provide an answer to the question....*) will discourage future readers from thinking the answer is appropriate - can that warning be removed?

Comment: I often see this happen when reviewing. If a comment from review is wrong, I find it best to answer them: "Fellow reviewers: this _is_ an answer, because ....".

Answer (score 7):

Despite what the "From Review" link might suggest, review comments are actually just regular comments and not some special notice or warning — which means you can either reply to the user directly, or flag it just like any other comment. There's no guarantee the comment will go away, of course, but that doesn't stop you from trying.

Comment: (psst, he's asking for tools)

Comment: I don't think he's asking for tools *per se*. It might be that the answer to the question is a tool, but that's incidental. He's asking how to perform a particular task. I'm not convinced this one merits closure.